# clojure gen-class with annotation that require enum parameter

Tags: java, spring, http, clojure, gen-class

I want to write a clojure lib and exposes generated classes, so that other java projects could use it.
I read and followed the gen-class doc, and everything works as my expect, except class annotation with enum parameters.

```clj
(ns common.exception.unauthorized
  (:gen-class :name
    ^{org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus
      org.springframework.http.HttpStatus/UNAUTHORIZED}  ; <- here
              com.lalala.common.exception.Unauthorized
              :extends java.lang.RuntimeException
              :init init
              :constructors {[String] [String]}
              :main false
              :prefix "unauthorized-"))

(defn unauthorized-init [^String message]
  [[message] nil])
```

This exception class is generated without any error, and it also able  be used as an `Exception`. However, this exception is intended to be used as a http response along with spring web. The spring framework read the annotation, and find that it is `HttpStatus/UNAUTHORIZED` then response 401. But the spring framework throws exception complaining that `java.lang.EnumConstantNotPresentException: org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`.

And I had a look at the generated class, it's something like this:

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.401)
public class Unauthorized extends RuntimeException {
    private static final Var init__var = Var.internPrivate("common.exception.unauthorized", "unauthorized-init");
    private static final Var getStackTrace__var = Var.internPrivate("common.exception.unauthorized", "unauthorized-getStackTrace");
    // ...... ellipsis
}
```

As it shown, the `HttpStatus/UNAUTHORIZED` is compiled into `HttpStatus.401` which is invalid.

I also tried with `{:code org.springframework.http.HttpStatus/UNAUTHORIZED}`, `{:value org.springframework.http.HttpStatus/UNAUTHORIZED}`, it can be compiled into `@ResponseStatus(code/value = HttpStatus.401)`, but the enum value itself still in invalid form `HttpStatus.401`.

Am I use class annotation for gen-class in a wrong way? or just Clojure compiler just have this bug?

P.S. tried with Clojure 1.9, 1.10, 1.10.1

Comment: IMO `gen-class` is in general a mug's game. If you need to produce Java classes for Java interop, javac is really good at making them, so I write a small Java wrapper for the logic that I implement in Clojure. That Java wrapper can have whatever annotations and other weird stuff Java libraries expect, but it communicates with my Clojure code in a straightforward, data-driven way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use native Java code instead. I realized that writing classes in clojure with only ctor forwarded to super class is making trouble for myself.
I embedded java code in the project along with `:java-source-paths` configured in `defproject`, got my problem solved.